# Gym effect at evening

Tags: gym

What is best time for gym and exercise? Till now I was going to gym in morning. But now due to some timing change in my job , I will have to go gym in the evening.

But I have heard from many people that morning gym is more effective than evening , Is that correct? Also how to get energy to do gym at evening after full day job?

Comment: The most effective will be the time when you can work the hardest. For me, that's definitely not the morning. Eat something between your workday and gym session to get some time and food to recover mentally.

Comment: @Mårten I strongly agree with the first part. However , personally, when i have the time,I don't eat until I have worked out. Somehow I feel like I have more energy in the gym.

Comment: Ok so should I do like eat something after my job and then go direct to gym?

Comment: That works well for me. @s3v3ns, I've had similar experiences but also times when I've felt very sluggish, so I'm not taking any chances :)

Comment: okay..thanks all for nice advice. I will follow same.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consensus is that there is no best time to workout,  but rather that the best time is the one which will allow you to be committed to your training program.  The reason for this is that exercising consistently gives long term benefits which outweigh the difference between a morning and evening workout.

Your preference for morning versus evening training will depend in part on your body's circadian rhythm, which is something like your body's own metabolic clock.  If you feel lethargic and out of energy when you wake up then you probably won't want to go on a 10K run in the middle of winter.  To answer your question, if you feel exhausted after leaving the office, then your body may be telling you to train in the morning.  Perhaps you can find time during lunch for a workout?

There are some differences between a morning and evening workout.  Working out hard late in the evening can cause insomnia.  Normally in the late evening your brain increases its production of melatonin, and your body's metabolism slows down.  This is all supposed to get you ready to sleep, but a hard workout can prevent this.  I can personally attest that late night workouts can cause big insomnia.  And I have paid the price for this many times, as I often had to wake up early the next morning to train again.

There is an [excellent article](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/topicoftheweek70.htm) on BodyBuilding.com which compares many exercise parameters during morning, noon, and evening.

Other sources:
[American Heart Association](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/GettingHealthy/PhysicalActivity/When-Is-the-Best-Time-of-Day-to-Work-Out_UCM_438922_Article.jsp)
[WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/features/whats-the-best-time-to-exercise)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Yesterday I have tried to do gym at evening[After my job day completion] but I was not able to do more exercise. I did not able to identify that it was because I was tried mentally OR physically. So I think I will have to do it in morning. which would be best for me..

Answer (score -3):

Well for the experts advise there is no alternate to the morning exercise - You wake up with full relaxed muscles then you have some healthy diet with some workouts your muscles got enough time till night to react with the work out you performed giving you maximum results with healthy body and mind.

Rest there are many instructors or gym people who you see exercising in the evening and that's also normal if you feel that your job don't make you too tired and you can have healthy diet at-least 30 mins before starting gym with a relax mind you can obtain almost any kind of results you want.

Conclusion: There is no alternate to the morning gym but even is the second choice.